# While True looping the results of a 'if elif' statement

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I'm experimenting with While loops and I encountered this:

CODE:

```
x = int(input('Guess the number 1-10'))

while True:
    if (x == 8):
        print('yay!')
        break
    else:
        print('No No')
```

RESULT:

```
No No
No No
No No
No No
No No
No No
No No
No No
```

**forever until I stop it...**

Some people have suggested to use break, but I don't want to stop it on one try when they get it wrong, I want it to give multple tries until they get the right number. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to ask the user for input in every iteration:

```
while True:
    x = int(input('Guess the number 1-10'))

    if (x == 8):
        print('yay!')
        break
    else:
        print('No No')
```